# Networkdays Function for range of cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am building a macro which will compare dates (in date format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm) from column AO with dates (in date format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm) in column AL and it will print their difference in working days to the column AS (just the number of the days, not minutes etc.) I have searched and found that NETWORKDAYS is a function in excel that does that but I dont know how to implement it for a range in VBA. My code so far, is pretty similar to one I found in the web but it is for specific dates, not for a range. Any ideas? Much appreciated!

What I have so far is this, but it says there is an error in line with d1=cell.Offset... I dont now why!

```
Dim d1 As Range, d2 As Range, wf As WorksheetFunction
'Dim N As Long
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
For Each cell In Range(Range("AT2"), Range("AT2").End(xlDown))
Set d1 = cell.Offset(0, -4)
Set d2 = cell.Offset(0, -7)
cell.Value = wf.NetworkDays(d1.Value2, d2.Value2)
Next cell
```

Comment: Isnt the for each cell considered as a loop?

Comment: sorry did not see the edit.

Comment: You need to `Set` ranges: `Set d1 = cell.Offset(0, -4)`

Comment: now it says that the problem is in the line cell.Value = wf.NetworkDays(d1, d2)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Try `(d1.Value2,d2.Value2)`  If that does not work make sure the dates are in the correct order, if that does not work make sure the values are true dates and are being passed into the variables correctly.  After that I am out of ideas.

Comment: now it gives an error in line Set d1.Value2 = cell.Offset(0, -4) saying error 91:Object variable or With block not set

Comment: I will update again the code as it is now

Comment: Replace `cell.Value = wf.NetworkDays(d1, d2)` with `cell.Value = [atpvbaen.xls].NetworkDays(d1, d2)`. And make sure you activate `atpvbaen.xls` in Tools --> References.

Comment: hmm I cannot seem to find this atpvbaen.xls in Tools --> References.

Comment: Tools->References in the VBA Editor. But maybe its because I have a prehistoric version (2003, running in WinXP....)

Comment: yes I have been looking for it for a while and its nowhere.. to be honest, there is not even one with an ending .xls

Comment: You do not set .value2, you use .value2 in the function: `cell.Value = wf.NetworkDays(d1.value2, d2.value2)`

Comment: Remove the `.Value2` from the `Set` lines.

Comment: ok it seems its close to working but before it runs it says error 1004 : Unable to get the NetworkDays property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: I just edited the code .. its the most updated version .. this gets the error 1004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a 'hybrid' approach as you are going to use a worksheet function anyway: let VBA fill in the function, replace the output with values:

```
    Sub WorkDaysDiff()
    ' w-b 2017-08-26

    Dim rng As Range, lastrow As Long

    ' assuming columns A, B hold dates, results into column C
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("C1"), .Range("C" & lastrow))
    End With

    With rng
        ' write formula into worksheet cells for whole range at once
        ' and replace it with their value after recalculation
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],RC[-2])"
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

This way, you avoid looping which might save time if the range is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this. It may also be a VBA function, I'm not sure. [image]

Comment: I know how to do it manually in excel, but its part of a macro, so it has to be in a vba!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date

    For Each Cell In Range(Range("AT2"), Range("AT2").End(xlDown))
        d1 = Cell.Offset(0, -4)
        d2 = Cell.Offset(0, -7)
        Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(d1, d2)
    Next Cell
```

Comment: It says type mismatch for line  d1 = Cell.Offset(0, -4)

Comment: that means that your data is not Date type, but probably String. so you cannot do date manipulation on the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use column AL and AO, and put the results in AS - with the range determined by what is in AT - use the following:

```
Dim d1 As Range, d2 As Range, wf As WorksheetFunction
'Dim N As Long
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
For Each cell In Range(Range("AT2"), Range("AT2").End(xlDown))
Set d1 = cell.Offset(0, -5)
Set d2 = cell.Offset(0, -8)
cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = wf.NetworkDays(d1.Value2, d2.Value2)
Next cell
```